# Trying to activate a sheet after opening a workbook with workbooks.open

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck. I'm running an array to open selected files, which do open, but once I begin to attempt to add processing code I can't seem to activate the sheets I want. I try and debug on `strShName` and the variable never gets populated, always null, but the variable `ExpRptFileName(N)` does get populated with the full path and file name.ext. 
I'm wondering if the path should be removed (which I've tried with several variations but it fails) or if the type of loop I'm using is hanging me up.

In the following code, the variable ExpRptID is null; doesn't pull the data from the sheet......while the variable ExpRptFileName(N) contains the proper path, file name, and file ext.

Here's the code:

```
ExpRptFileNameInLoop = Right(ExpRptFileName(N), Len(ExpRptFileName(N)) - InStrRev(ExpRptFileName(N), Application.PathSeparator, , 1))

If bIsBookOpen(ExpRptFileNameInLoop) = False Then

            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(ExpRptFileName(N))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                Workbooks.Open ExpRptFileName(N)



Dim ExpRptID As String
ExpRptID = Sheets("Expense Report").Range("R3").Value

Exit Sub
Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
' ************** Notes here
On Error Resume Next
bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, but... in your VBE, please select your code to be posted here, hit Tab once, then copy paste here (Edit post) to draw people reading it.

Comment: Why would you want to activate a sheet? Best practice would be to absolutely reference a sheet, either by name or by sheet number. Also provide us with a minimal verifyable example, so clean up all the mess from your code, as it is hard for us to see what is the actual problem within the mess there is.

Comment: Argh. Just retyped everything and then lost it....